# Shifting codes from Microsoft Excel Object To Module

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Is it possible to transfer codes from a microsoft excel object to a module automatically? So it's like writing a macro to shift the codes from one place to another?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  An object like what for example?  Do you mean something like this? - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Oh yeah great link! I think that's what I want to do. So as per screenshot updated, I have a set of codes in Sheet1 (Sheet1), i was just wondering earlier on if its possible to copy or shift the codes out to `Module 1`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Just FYI if you have code in a worksheet and copy the sheet, the code gets copied too, I've used that quite a few times to propagate code without referencing the VB project but then again I dunno your purpose.

Comment: Automatically moving (without reading) code from worksheet to normal module is a very bad idea. All event handlers will stop working. Also if the code does not use fully qualified objects (e.g. `Range`) - the results may change.